# Excel setting an indirect cell value

Tags: excel, cell

I have three columns, A, B, C.  In column C I have a variable value 1,2,3 etc., in column 2 I want to have an equation such that A gets set based on the value of C.

For example: if(c=1,cell(A)="illegal", if(c=2,cell(A)="legal",""))

Is this possible, how do I do it?

Note: this is a simple example of what I want to accomplish, Columns A-Z will be filled in with Text data from a third party, column C (AC in reality) is referenced from another spreadsheet.  Basically filling in the blanks.

I know I could do this with a macro but I don't want to if I can get away with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pertinent to your task description, you can enter the Worksheet formula in `Cell A1`

```
=IF(C1=2,"legal",IF(C1=1,"illegal",""))
```

and then expand it to the entire range in `column A`. The text in this column will correspond to values 1 or 2 in the `Column C` (as per your description). For any other value in `Column C` it will show blank (`""`).

Though your task description isn't clear enough, but if by "indirect cell reference" you mean getting the text from cells in another worksheet (instead of hardcoding it) then you can follow the example shown below:

```
=IF(C1=2,Sheet2!C1,IF(C1=1,Sheet2!C2,""))
```

where the actual text is stored in Sheet2, cells C1 and C2, correspondingly. Also, you can apply the absolute reference (i.e., cell column/row prefixed by `$` sign as shown below), depends on your business logic:

```
=IF(C1=2,Sheet2!$C$1,IF(C1=1,Sheet2!$C$2,""))
```

There are couple other Excel Worksheet Functions, which may be useful pertinent to your case: `INDEX(Range, RowNum, ColumnNum)` and  `INDIRECT(refText,boolVal)`; in the latter `refText` contains the reference to a Cell either in A1 style (if `boolVal=TRUE`, or just omitted), or R1C1 style (if `boolVal=FALSE`).

Hope this will help. Regards,

Comment: On a related note, an easy way to fill this down is to reselect A1 after the formula has been input and double-click the tiny black square *fill handle* in the lower-right of the cell selection border.

Comment: That's basic Excel.  I added the note very specifically that A-Z will be used as text data, there can be no formulas.  I want to accomplish indirect cell reference updating as noted.  May be if I said "formula in column AB will set column A if column AC is set" it might be easier to see what i want to do.  This is easy in Assembler language, there we call it indirect registry reference.  Can I do it in Excel?

Comment: @Sean: your task description (with added comments) looks more like a development project spec rather than a question. Please show your code snippet and narrow down your question to a specific problem with your code. It could be a VBA or Excel Worksheet. Thanks and regards,

Comment: I'm going to mark this post for deletion, it seems indirect cell addressing is either not understood or impossible.  I have written a macro to do the job.  I will mark Alex's answer as correct though it is normal =if(a=a,setthiscell,"") and not what I was looking for =if(cellb=b, setADifferentCellAtOffset(-2),"")

Comment: @Sean: Thanks for accepting the answer. I have added couple more Excel Functions that you may use to modify the solution pertinent to your particular requirements. Best regards,